# Enable of disable a button depending on the value of a variable

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java

I have a button and I need to enable/disable it depending on the value of an integer and I don't manage to set the observer on the variable . I tried something like

```
Subject<Integer> mObservable = PublishSubject.create();

 public void observe() {
        mObservable.map(value -> {
            boolean enabled;
            enabled = value != 0;
            return enabled;
        }).subscribe( mButton.setEnabled(genres))
    }
```

Comment: do you want to change your button state based on integer value you get from observable

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
 public void observe() {
        mObservable.map(value -> {
            boolean enabled;
            enabled = value != 0;
            return enabled;
        }).subscribe( new Observer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                        System.out.println("onNext: " + integer);

                           if(integer!=){
                            mButton.setEnabled(true);  
                            }else{
                               mButton.setEnabled(false);  
                             }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
 });
    }
```